# Flutter How to check there is any time within certain time?

Tags: flutter

I want to check there is any time within certain time. Clearly, I got a list:

```
List<String> timeSlots = [];
```

This list returning me times like this: `[08:30,09:00,...,22:00]`

And I got current phone time. And I am creating `listViewBuilder`.

I just want to check if current phone time between 08:30-09:00 and I want to set my `Card` color which it's `listViewBuilder's` returning widget.

Comment: You want to check if the current phone is between the range of the first two time slots ?

Comment: Yes, exactly like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is use the [isAfter](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.14.1/dart-core/DateTime/isAfter.html) & [isBefore](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/DateTime/isBefore.html) methods of `DateTime`. So you will have to create `DateTime`s out of the first two times :

```dart
  List<String> timeSlots = ["08:30", "09:00", "22:00"];

  DateTime currentTime = DateTime.now();

  DateTime date1 = DateTime.parse(
      "${currentTime.year}-${currentTime.month < 10 ? '0${currentTime.month}' : currentTime.month}-${currentTime.day} ${timeSlots[0]}:00");
  
  DateTime date2 = DateTime.parse(
       "${currentTime.year}-${currentTime.month < 10 ? '0${currentTime.month}' : currentTime.month}-${currentTime.day} ${timeSlots[1]}:00");

  print(currentTime.isAfter(date1) && currentTime.isBefore(date2));
```

There may be other prettier ways though ^^

Comment: Hello, thanks this worked but I got another problem with my ListView. I changed your code timeSlots[index] instead of  timeSlots[0] and timeSlots[1]. I have 30 item in my listViewBuilder. I set the date2's timeSlots[1] to timeSlots[index+1]. But It return me an error after last item. Because I think this code try to generate index+1 but there is no more item after last item. How can we handle with that ?

Comment: Check if you are on not on last item then create the dates, `if (index!=timeSlots.length){ your code }`